# Hibernate + JSF connection with the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I have a doubt, I searched in several places and could not axar anything about it, then the area of the experts I ask.

Is there any relationship between the scopes of JSF and duration of the connection to the database hibernate?

I've noticed that happens some connections remain open constantly, and also that the connections are always connections with session scope in most cases, so far as I understand, the connections are kept open while the scope is active.

Sometime later, I'm using more ViewScope, and this connection problem abated somewhat.

I do not know if my doubts proceeds, but anyone know if this relationship JSF + Hibernate actually exists, it comes in connection with the database?

I thank you.

Comment: In other words, you're assigning a Hibernate session as a property of a session scoped JSF managed bean? Why exactly? This isn't how they are supposed to be used.

Comment: I do not know if it's the correct way. But from what you said, I can not open a Hibernate session in SessionScoped or no scope?

Comment: Surely you can, but you should absolutely not assign it as an instance variable of a class which lives longer than the resource itself is supposed to live (for exactly the same reasons as "plain vanilla" JDBC resources such as `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, etc). If you're in first place already unfamiliar with basic JDBC, it's recommended to take a Hibernate pause and take a step back to learn the mandatory basics which Hibernate is using under the covers.

Comment: Means that the hibernate session survived until the end of the class instance that was invoked regardless of scope?